# NgModel with dynamic fields in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, oop

I am trying to figure out how to re-use the same component/form for a model with dynamic fields.

**Background:** I have a form that will create a new record, based on the record type, the form will have different fields, I am trying to re-use the same `create.component.ts` and same methods to post different data.

My form looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="activeType === 'type1'">

  <input class="input-field" type="text"
         [(ngModel)]="externalSubscription.firstName" placeholder="Enter first name">
  <input class="input-field" type="text"
         [(ngModel)]="externalSubscription.lastName" placeholder="Enter last name">
</div>

<div *ngIf="activeType === 'type2'">
  <input class="input-field" type="text"
         [(ngModel)]="externalSubscription.userName" placeholder="Enter User Name">
  <input class="input-field" type="text"
         [(ngModel)]="externalSubscription.userId" placeholder="Enter User Id">
</div>
```

As you can see type one and type two has completely different fields, but I am trying to use externalSubscription model to bind this data.

For the first form - I'd like to initialize `externalSubscription` as:

```
externalSubscription = new ExternalSubscriptionType1(firstName, lastName);
```

and for the second it's:

```
externalSubscription = new ExternalSubscriptionType1(userName, userId);
```

Is there a good practice for cases like this? 
Or should I completely divide those forms into a different component that will use different classes?

They both use the same `POST` endpoint at the end.

Comment: How many more activeType's do you plan on using?  I ask because it's all about scale.  I wouldn't add any extra infrastructure for something as simple as your example.

Comment: @dan I don't expected to have more than ~5 active types